# Generate graphs from a given graph by permuting positions of directed edges

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

Assume that I have a mixed graph with some directed edges (the number of directed edges can be from 1 to 10). 
This is an example of such graph `g1` with 3 directed edges called `a, b, c`.

[image]

Now I would like to create all possible graphs which are formed by permuting  the directed edges.

From 3 directed edges, it is possible to generate 6 possible graphs below.

[image]

If `g1` is given, how can we create all 6 graphs from `g1` to `g6`? 
The condition of permuting directed edges are that the arrow direction should keep same and the two vertice associated with the edge should be moved together with the edge.

I'm trying to write a code to do this automatically for a graph with any number of directed edges less than 10. 
 Also it would be nice if it can be run quickly as I'll have to run it for billion times. 
(the edge label is not important, just for presenting the problem)

```
myGraph[edges_] := 
  Graph[edges, {EdgeStyle -> {Black}, 
    VertexLabels -> {Placed[Automatic, Above]}, 
    VertexLabelStyle -> {Red}, 
    VertexStyle -> {Directive[Red, EdgeForm[None]]}}];
g1 = myGraph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 
   6 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 7 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 
   9 \[UndirectedEdge] 10}]
```

Comment: You are changing the set of undirected edges.

Comment: @Alan yes, that is intended. I'm trying to do something like just moving these directed edges to exchange their positions.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just permute the directed edges. But then 2 edges would give 2 graphs not 4?

Comment: @DanielHuber yes, you're right. Sorry for the mistake. The nodes associated with an edge would also move together with the edge.

Comment: Any idea to solve this? It looks simple but doesn't seem easy to write code.

Comment: Your example is very special, namely a [path graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph) where directed edges are not adjacent. Are you only interested in graphs of this type? If yes, please clarify that in your question. If no, what is the expected output for `Graph[{1->2,2->3,3->1}]` (not a path graph) or `Graph[{1->2,3->2}]` (path graph where directed edges are adjacent)?

Comment: @user293787 I think I can consider it as path graph for now though I may want  to generalise it a bit  more later for a loop. You talked about some problems that I haven't thought before. Actually in my graph, two directed edges are never adjencent. They're always separated by one or more undirected edges. With that would it be possible to solve for a loop instead of path graph? If not then solving it as path graph would also be great.

Answer (score 3):

Define

```
permuteDirected[G_]:=With[{X=EdgeList[G,_DirectedEdge]},With[{S=Map[Sort,List@@@X]},
    EdgeList[G]/.Map[Thread[Flatten[S]->Flatten[#]]&,Permutations[S]]
               /.Thread[Map[Reverse,X]->X]]];
```

Then, assuming OP's code,

```
Map[myGraph,permuteDirected[g1]]
```

gives

[image]

This should work for path graphs where the names of the vertices are in canonical order, and where directed edges are not adjacent.